# TestUI.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details

Tags: java, swing, jlist, java-7, defaultlistmodel

```
    try{
        String[] mobileSuit;
        File packageFile = openDialogFile("Select", "Choose folder that contain overall mobile suit folder", JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        mobileSuit = packageFile.list();
        DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
        for(String el : mobileSuit){
            listModel.addElement(el);
        }
        this.packagePath = packageFile.getPath();
        JList_mobileSuit.setModel(listModel);
        JList_mobileSuit.setSelectedIndex(0);
    }catch(java.lang.NullPointerException e){

    }
```

When i uncomment " JList mobileSuit.setModel(listModel) " line,netbeans's output that report "TestUI.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. " .I'm still confused as to what I am doing wrong.Please help me

Comment: JList_mobileSuit is a javax.swing.JList and when i use DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();
netbeans report "redundant type arguments in new expression (use diamond operator instead) "

Answer (score 1):

it shoud be

```
DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();
```

and JList can take String too

```
JList<String> JList_mobileSuit = new JList<>(listModel);//JList<String>(listModel);
```

Comment: Note [*Type Inference for Generic Instance Creation*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html), new in Java 7.